# How to prevent form saving in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a general form which is based on a model class named 'factor'. in that form, there is an embedded form named 'customer', which is based on a model class named 'customer'.

Here is the related part of my schema.yml:

```
factor:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    customer_id: {type: bigint}
    final_sum: {type: Integer}
  relations:
    customer: {local:customer_id, foreign:id, alias: customer, foreignAlias:factors}

customer:
  columns:
    name: {type: string(255), notnull:true, unique:true}
```

when user submits the general form, I check if customer_name exists in customer table, and if so, I want the embedded form 'customer' not to be saved, because it leads to an error of column uniqueness!
instead I should set the factor customer_id to the id of customer which already exists in db.
how can i manage this?

Comment: Doctrine       [Comments must be at least 15 characters in length :D]

Comment: sorry i got to admit that i cant help you with doctrine, but just to mention it: propel would do this behaviour implicit. If the entry is existing it updates it, if not it creates it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You denys281 and glerendegui :)

The problem was simple, it can be solved by easily unsetting embedded customer form and updating factor form object.

I added the following lines in processForm function of actions.class.php file:

```
$pFactor=$form->getObject();

$customer=Doctrine_Query::create()->from('customer c')->where('c.name=?',$form['customer']['name']->getValue())->execute();

if(!empty($cus[0]))
{
    $pFactor->setCustomer($cus[0]);
    unset($form['customer']);
}

$form->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem in the logic of your web applications .. In my opinion, the problem is that you have there is not a **good practice**. There are people in the world, with the **same name and surname**, what will you do in this case? Or, if buyer enters a **wrong one letter** of his name? **Or if a bad guy enters someone else's name and surname**. If you made a unique user name field, then I think it would be good if you make registration, so you will avoid this problem, and you simply will set user_id in factor form in hidden field. There is a wonderful plugin that does everything instead of you [**sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin**](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to do it with embedded forms. Instead of that, use a simple factor form without the customer_id (use unset or useFields) and a simple customer form. 
Something like this in actions.class.php:

```
$this->factorForm = new SimpleFactorForm; // (without customer_id)
$this->customerForm = new CustomerForm; // 

if($request->getMethod() == sfRequest::POST) {
  $this->factorForm->bind($request->getPostParameter($this->factorForm->getName());
  $this->customerForm->bind($request->getPostParameter($this->customerForm->getName());

  if(($this->customerForm->isValid()) && ($this->factorForm->isValid()) ) {
    // customer unique validation -- create or find a uniqueCustomerObject
    // something like
    $uniqueCustomerObject = Doctrine::getTable('customer')->findOneBy('name',$this->customerForm->getValue('name'));
    if(!$uniqueCustomerObject) $uniqueCustomerObject=$this->customerForm->save();

    $this->factorForm->getObject()->setCustomer($uniqueCustomerObject);
    $factor = $this->factorForm->save();
  }
}
```

And, of course, in your template:

```
<form method="post">
 <?php echo $factorForm; ?>
 <?php echo $customerForm; ?>

</form>
```